# Wordpress: Mingle page with category navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having this situation:
In a Wordpress blog I have my main navigation persisting of categories. The navigation is being created with `wp_list_categories()`.

Now I'd like to mingle just one link to a page at a certain position within this navigation built of only categories.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Thanks a lot!
sprain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages and exclude the pages you don't want in the menu:

`<php wp_list_pages(title_li&exclude=X;);?>`

where 'X' is the id number of the page you want to exclude. Or use a plugin like [Exclude Pages.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages/)

Do the same with http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories to split the category listings and put the page listings within the category menu.

Use [Reveal IDs for WP Admin « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/reveal-ids-for-wp-admin-25/) to find page IDs.

Comment: Ok, I knew there was no easy solution :) I'll try this, thanks!